# Problema de visualización CardView en RecyclerView

Tags: android-studio, firebase, recyclerview, cardview

He comenzado un proyecto en Android Studio y necesito ayuda. No soy programador, ni he estudiado para ello, es decir, tengo poco conocimiento del tema pero me gustaría aprenderlo por mi cuenta y con ayuda de foros. No me enrollo más.

Estoy haciendo un proyecto que consiste en la gestionar la contabilidad de una empresa. Ya he creado layouts para la creación de asientos, modificación y visualización.

Ahora bien, quiero que los datos que tengo en la base de datos en Firebase aparezcan en un CardView, y este, en un ReclyclerView. He intentado mil maneras de hacerlo, mirando tutoriales, videoturoriales, adaptando un código (o el intento) y aún no tengo ningún resultado.

Para que veáis que quiero hacer os paso capturas de pantallas:[image: Esta sería la plantilla del CardView]

Y mi base de datos es esta:[image: Base de datos de Firebase]

Solo quiero mostrar en CardView los detalles de cada asiento. Un ejemplo sería: Asiento nº 1 - Descripción ASIENTO DE APERTURA - Cantidad (No me preocupa ahora mismo. Sería la suma del debe, por ejemplo).

Espero que alguien me pueda ayudar aportándome códigos, tutoriales, videos, lo que sea. Muchísimas gracias de antemano.

PD: Se me pasó colocar el código... Esto es lo que tengo:

**CardView**

public class CardView  {

```
private String asiento;
private String descripcion;
private String cantidad;

public CardView(){ }
public CardView(String asiento, String descripcion, String cantidad) {
    this.asiento = asiento;
    this.descripcion = descripcion;
    this.cantidad = cantidad;
}

public String getCantidad() {
    return cantidad;
}
public void setCantidad(String cantidad) {
    this.cantidad = cantidad;
}
public String getDescripcion()
{return descripcion;}

public void setDescripcion(String descripcion) {
    this.descripcion = descripcion;}

public String getAsiento() {
    return asiento;
}
public void setAsiento(String asiento) {
    this.asiento = asiento;
}
```

**Layout donde va situado RecyclerView**

public class Asientos extends AppCompatActivity {

```
ImageButton btagregar;
RecyclerView recyclerView;
DatabaseReference mdatabase;
private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_asientos);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_v);
    btagregar = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btagregar);

    btagregar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(Asientos.this, CrearAsientos.class));
        }
    });


LinearLayoutManager horizontalLayoutManagaer=new LinearLayoutManager(this,LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(horizontalLayoutManagaer);
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    mdatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users");
    mdatabase.keepSynced(true);
    'FireBase RecyclerAdapter
    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<CardView, BlogerViewHolder> 
     firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new
            FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<CardView, BlogerViewHolder>(
            CardView.class,
            R.layout.activity_card_view,
            BlogerViewHolder.class,
            mdatabase
    ){
                @Override
                protected void populateViewHolder(BlogerViewHolder 
                viewHolder, CardView model, int position) {
                    viewHolder.setAsiento(model.getAsiento());
                    viewHolder.setDescripcion(model.getDescripcion());
                    viewHolder.setCantidad(model.getCantidad());
                }

            };

    recyclerView.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
}

public static class BlogerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    View myCard;
    TextView txt,txt2,txt3;

    public BlogerViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        myCard=itemView;
    }
    public void setAsiento(String asiento) {
        txt = (TextView) myCard.findViewById(R.id.asiento);
        txt.setText(asiento);
    }
    public void setDescripcion(String descripcion) {
        txt2 = (TextView) myCard.findViewById(R.id.descripcion);
        txt2.setText(descripcion);
    }
    public void setCantidad(String cantidad) {
        txt3 = (TextView) myCard.findViewById(R.id.cantidad);
        txt3.setText(cantidad);
    }
}
```

Muchas gracias!!

Comment: Mas importante que las imágenes aquí es el código.

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio Dani!, te invito a realizar el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Con respecto a la realización de preguntas que estas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas excelentes respuestas, **es muy importante leer [ask]** en base a este documento debes modificar tu pregunta, es recomendable agregar lo que has intentado e investigado, saludos!